# sql server database security vs server security

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication

I noticed I can create login under sql server/security tree node. I can also create login under sql server/databases/database name/security tree node. My question is what's the difference between those two security logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that a user gets access to SQL Server is first the user (whether they are a Windows Login or a SQL Server login) is created at the instance level - at the server/security tree node. Once a login is created the user is created,sql server/databases/database name/security tree node,from a login, at each database that they will interact with. Some users by being made a member of certain groups (such as be as a member of SQL Server System Adminstrators have permissions on all databases) but almost all other logins need to be be added to each database that they will need to work on.

So if Windows User Joe needs to read certain tables in the Sales database first a login would be created at the instance level and then Joe would be added to the sales database and assigned permissions on the objects they need to do their work.

Comment: Please can you explain what happens if an user is in database/security but NOT in server/security tree? Its login is simply deniend? I have a case when I found many users in database tree but they are not in server tree and.

Comment: This is a common issue that usually comes about when a database is attached to an instance. It is called an orphan user. Sometimes the user exists at both levels but they have different SIDS (Security IDS). Remember that users typically have permission on objects and/or may be members of groups that give them permissions. Dropping a user means all the permissions go away. If a user owns an object they cannot be dropped. Obviously users that don't exist at the instance level cannot log in.

Comment: I saw it happens always when I restore a database from another server, in this case I have to delete the user from database/security and reapply user mappings from server/security. Thanks

Comment: See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
on how to use 

        sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix', 'login_name_here'
to fix orphaned users that have corresponding database and instance names, but different SID's.